# And nobody came between us or could ever "come above"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

The following is a part of a verse from the song *[Baby](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/justinbieber/baby.html)* by Justin Bieber.

> When I was 13, I had my first love,
>   There was nobody that compared to my baby
>   And nobody came between us or could ever come above
>   She had me going crazy, oh, I was star-struck,
>   She woke me up daily, don’t need no Starbucks.

In line three, what does *come above* mean? I was able to find the meaning of the phrasal verb *come between*, but I wasn't able to find the meaning of *come above*. The phrase seems non-existent as there are *come across*, *come upon*, *come under*, *come around*, *come over*, *come down*, or *go above and beyond* that I encountered which I already know the meanings of some, but not *come above*. So what does the phrase mean in this context?

Edit: There are actually three versions of this lyric that I found. One wrote "And nobody came between us *who* could ever come above". The second wrote "And nobody came between us *no-one* could ever come above", and there's this one "And nobody came between us *or* could ever come above". I'm not sure which one is the real one and not sure whether that'll affect the meaning of the phrase. This is a rapping part and it was too fast for me to distinguish the actual version.

Comment: I don't think song lyric interpretation is on-topic for this site. You can't take everything you hear in a song literally. The meaning might be *nothing else was as important to me as our relationship* or *no other relationship was better/more perfect than ours* or any number of other meanings; art is open to interpretation. I suggest this question be closed as off-topic; I'll monitor as the community weighs in.

Comment: I agree that it's Off Topic, but not because it's a lyric (lyrics are not inherently non-Standard) but because it's dialect. Which is not to say that it's going to remain dialect!

Comment: @StoneyB: The ELL FAQ doesn't explicitly debar "lyric interpretation", but I'd be more than happy if it did. If the only citation for a usage that the OP can find is a song lyric, the chances are I won't think it should be asked about here. It'll be Too Localised, Off Topic Lit Crit, or otherwise unsuitable - as your own answer effectively acknowledges.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd be just as quick to close it (after answering it at least in a comment, because I think every question that can't be looked up in a dictionary deserves an answer) if OP had asked about the UK football-fan version of *come above*, meaning to achieve a higher rank in the standings - slang's just another kind of dialect. Some lyrics are dialect, some newspapers are dialect (just ask Yoishi-san!), some (most?) formal academic prose is dialect. We shouldn't close because of the form but because of the content.

Comment: @StoneyB Lyrics are _particular_ about grammar. Explaining the lyrics of a song is not the purpose of EL&U, and it should not be the purpose of ELL, which is for people who is learning English.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Balderdash. I learned German listening to Marlene Dietrich and *Dreigroschenoper* alongside reading the Duden *Grammatik*. Bob Dylan and Paul Simon write better English than most lawyers, and more fun, too, which last time I looked was an integral part of learning.

Comment: @StoneyB Feel free to learn a language as you prefer; this is not "Song lyrics Stack Exchange."

Comment: @kiamlaluno And do you extend the same freedom to our visitors? It's not "Urban Hipster Slang.SE" either, but [your own top-voted answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/700/32) addressed just such a use. And your [second-most-highly-voted answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/439/32) did not shy away from addressing the use of English in a song lyric. OP here asks us not for the meaning of a lyric but the for the meaning of single phrase, which happens to occur in a lyric; that's On Topic at ELU and I think should be fair game here, too.

Comment: @StoneyB My most up-voted answer has nothing to share with which questions are off-topic. If you think those questions are off-topic, by all means vote to close them. I didn't answer what a phrase means in a song; I answered what the phrase would mean when used outside a song. Neither of those answers of mine have been even accepted.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Exactly my principle. I like your answers, I think those questions are appropriate, I think *this* question is appropriate and only wants closing because the phrase in question is not now used outside a relatively closed speech community - which OP could not know, because the song went out under the name of an extremely whitebread performer. I think we're 99% in agreement.

Comment: I sincerely hope that questions on lyrics will be permitted on this site because I agree that listening to songs is an integral part of language learning and it has helped me tremendously in my English learning. Like many English learners, when asking a lyrical question I often don't realize that a certain phrase can be open to such multiple interpretatitons, and so I think the decision to close questions on lyrics should depend on its content and not the lyric itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find *come above* all over Google in hip-hop and AAVE contexts meaning either *achieve a higher status* or *be of more importance*. I think the latter is meant: "Nobody was more important to us than each other."

This is not Standard English (as you might expect, since it seems this verse was composed and performed by the rapper Ludacris). The closest equivalent in SE would be *come **before***; but that's rather literary.

In any case, it's not a locution you're likely to have much use for over the next few years.